# How to set default variable collection in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to have something like this:

```
with tf.variable_scope("yes", default_collection=["A", "B"]):
   ...
```

Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Use TF-Slim's [arg_scope](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py) combined with arg_scope aware [variable](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py)

Answer (score 0):

This is not very convenient, but you could define a `custom_getter` using `tf.variable_scope`:

```
def make_local_getter(getter, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['collections'] is None:
        kwargs['collections'] = []
    kwargs['collections'] += [tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]
    return getter(*args, **kwargs)

with tf.variable_scope(scope, custom_getter=make_local_getter):
    tf.get_variable(...)
```